# Enable a <span> nested in a disabled jQuery mobile Checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm using the jQuery Mobile CheckboxRadio widget to have a list of checkboxes on a mobile site. (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/checkboxradio-checkbox/)
Nested inside each checkbox there is the checkbox text/label, as well as a span element that has the word "Enable". I gave the span an onclick, which right now just does `alert("HI")` but here is what I would like it to do:

I would like the checkboxes to start off disabled, and then by clicking the span INSIDE the checkbox, the checkbox will enable. To enable the checkbox programmatically is simple, but the problem is this:

When the jQuery checkbox is set to disabled, it disables everything inside of it - including the span that has the onclick to enable it!

```html
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" disabled> <span onclick="enable()">Enable</span> Text of checkbox here.</label>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" disabled> <span onclick="enable()">Enable</span> Text of checkbox here.</label>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" disabled> <span onclick="enable()">Enable</span> Text of checkbox here.</label>

</fieldset>
```

**Is there any way to enable just that part of the textbox? Or maybe certain properties of the disabled checkbox can be changed inline by the span element?** I've tried playing around, to no avail, because I don't understand what happens behind the scenes when the checkbox disables.

Comment: You've provided your HTML but you've omitted the jQuery/JavaScript and any CSS you might have for those elements. Can you provide a complete [MCVE] for us to work with, in order that we can reproduce the problems you're experiencing and so offer you an answer?

Comment: what is the use of disabling them in the first place? you either have disabled or enabled. you can control checking/unchecking them whenever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing ( in case anyone finds this and could use the help) is using a split list view. I put the "enable" button on the right side as the small split icon, and the left checkbox was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to enable a element that is disabled with the html `disabled` attr, is to wrap something around it.

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-disabled)

Best way around this problem is to use the jquerymobile attr `data-disabled="true"`
Maybe you have to style your labels with some css.

```html
  
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

  
<label>
     <input name="checkbox-0 " type="checkbox" disabled>disabled
</label>
<label>
     <input name="checkbox-1 " type="checkbox" data-disabled="true">data-disabled -- <span onclick="alert('hi')">Enable</span>
</label>
<label>
    <input name="checkbox-2 " type="checkbox">enabled
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well here is a solution for it, not completely perfect but works

```
<fieldset>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" disabled> <span id="clickable1">Enable</span> Text of checkbox here. </label>

            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" disabled> <span id="clickable2">Enable</span> Text of checkbox here. </label> 

            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" disabled> <span id="clickable3">Enable</span> Text of checkbox here. </label>

        </fieldset>
```

and JS is as follows

```
 $("#clickable1").click(function(){
$("#checkbox1").attr("disabled",false);
});
$("#clickable2").click(function(){ 
$("#checkbox2").attr("disabled",false);
});
$("#clickable3").click(function(){
$("#checkbox3").attr("disabled",false);
});
```

NOTE : 1 thing that needs to be remembered is that no two ids could be same, as you have made every checkbox id as checkbox1 which is wrong

**Here is the working Example** - [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/susmhh5u/)

Comment: I don't understand why it helps to add the onclick programmatically. It still can't be clicked when the checkbox is disabled.

Comment: I myself got into this same problem and thats how i did it. in regards to onclick not working (thats what i m still trying to figure out)

Comment: And the above code works same as JS is launched on .click event which is equivalent of onclick in html event